# How can I calculate the number of states for a system consisting of two classical particles moving in one dimension?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics

The two particles move from $0$ to $L$ in one dimension and their hamiltonians are

\begin{equation}
H_{i}=cp_{i}
\end{equation}

I am thinking of using the expression:

\begin{equation}
\textbf{N}(E)=\frac{1}{N!}\int\frac{d\Gamma}{(2\pi\hbar)^{f}}\Theta(E-H) 
\end{equation}

where N is the number of particles, $d\Gamma$ is the differential volume element in the phase space, $\Theta$ the Heaviside step function and $f$ the degrees of freedom, but I don´t know exactly how to use it.

Comment: What do you have to find?

Comment: The number of states for that system, $\textbf{N}(E)$.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to use the canonical partition function and than finding a relation between temperature and energy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That integral is integrating over all states with energy less or equal than $E$, the factorial $N!$ is only used when particles are indistinguishable and the term $\frac{1}{h^{f}}$ can be pulled out of the integral since it is constant.

This way, the number of states only depends on the form of the hamiltonian of the system, so the method used to evaluate this integral depends also on the form of the hamiltonian $H(q,p)$.